# Taxes Rejected when e-filing

Tags: united-states, taxes

So I used TurboTax to do my taxes for the year. I e-filed like I normally do and it came back with error code

"R0000-902-01 - Taxpayer TIN in the Return Header must not be the same as a TIN of a previously accepted electronic return for the return type and tax period indicated in the tax return."

I am assuming some one stolen my identity and filed my taxes already. Which really sucks since I owe about $7000 on top of dealing with this.

What is the proper course of action now?

Comment: https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0008-tax-related-identity-theft

Comment: @keshlam can you make it an answer?

Comment: @littleadv: I didn't feel up to recopying half the page to keep from having to argue about link-only answers, and I don't play the points game. If you wait I'll probably do so eventually,  or you can do so yourself; I'm wholly indifferent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a clear sign of identity theft - someone filed a return using your TIN. There are several resources to use in this case.

1. [The FTC page on tax-related identity theft](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0008-tax-related-identity-theft),
2. [The IRS page on the matter](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Identity-Protection),
3. [Credit Freeze resources](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0497-credit-freeze-faqs)

You should familiarize yourself with the [IP PIN](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Get-An-Identity-Protection-PIN) and expect to receive one next filing season, once you've followed [the instructions on the IRS site](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Taxpayer-Guide-to-Identity-Theft).

For this year's return - you'll need to paper-file it, attaching a completed [form 14039](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f14039.pdf) to it.